# How to push value to array if all keywords match?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, search

I just created a basic use case for my problem where i got stuck , i will have `searchStr` keywords array object from client , i will check if all search keywords matches with line only than push line to `results`. with below code its always returning empty array of `results`, How to solve this problem or any better way to achieve this task ?

search.js

```
var line = "ticketNumber:45287,Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer "

var searchStr = [{
    "text": "45287"
}, {
    "text": "standard"
}]

var results = [];

function matchSearchStr(line, searchStrArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < searchStrArray.length; i++) {
        if (line.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchStrArray[i].toLowerCase()) != -1) {
            results.push({
                filename: "file",
                value: line
            });
           console.log(results);
        }

    }

}

matchSearchStr(line, searchStr)
```

Comment: Any reason not to write `searchStr = ["45287", "standard"]`?

Comment: i am using angular `ngInputTags` that is creating array object when you enter keywords

Comment: Unrelated, but instead of using globals, create the `results` inside the search function and return it.

Comment: Also unrelated, but you're going to end up with duplicate results with your current algorithm.

Comment: Can i get proper solution to get it resolve i am been stuck last 2 hours..

Comment: @le_m i can create array string but how i will implement logic still dont understand can you help me there

Comment: @hussain You need to find out why the solution below doesn't work for you - it indicates that there is another issue with your code. Can you add a `console.log(searchStrArray);` before the loop within `matchSearchStr` and report back what it prints? Or even better, add a `debugger;` statement and inspect the variables via your browser's debugger (press [F12]) and check whether or not it is really an array of objects with `text` properties,

Comment: [ '45287', 'industry' ] this is what it prints because i have mapped just array strings

Comment: That isn't what your code indicates-you're passing in the array of objects.

Comment: as i mentioned i am sending now array of string to resolve `toLowerCase` undefined issue now its sending all the results without a match.

Answer (score 0):

your are not searching on TEXT in your searchStrArray; try this:

```
function matchSearchStr(line, searchStrArray) {
    for (var i = 0; i < searchStrArray.length; i++) {

        if (line.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchStrArray[i].text.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
            results.push({
                filename: "file",
                value: line
            });
           console.log(results);
        }

    }

}
```

---- OWNER EDIT OF @aorfevre reply

here is actual code that i am trying to implement now i have chnaged object array to array string in this case it sends all the results.

```
    async.eachSeries(filesData.logFiles, function (logfile,done) {
            // read file
            readStream = fs.createReadStream('./logs/' + filesData.searchEnv  + '/'+ logfile.filename,'utf8')
             readStream.pipe(split())
              .on('data', function (line) {

              console.log(searchStr);
              for(var i=0; i<searchStr.length; i++)  {
                if (line.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchStr[i].toLowerCase()) != -1)
           var messageDateInfo = line.split('|')[0].replace(/[\[\]']+/g,'');
                messageDateInfo = new Date( messageDateInfo ).getTime();
                searchStartDate = new Date( searchStartDate ).getTime();
                searchEndDate = new Date( searchEndDate ).getTime();
                if( messageDateInfo - searchStartDate > 0 && searchEndDate - messageDateInfo > 0){
                  // console.log("message date is within this time range");
                  results.push({
                    filename:logfile.filename,
                    value:line
                  });
                }
             }
          });
                  done();
        }
        , function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('error', err);
            }
           readStream.on('end',function(){
            callback(results);
           });
           results = [];
        });
      }

    }
```

Comment: i got this error if i add `text` TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Comment: @hussain Then you're doing something else wrong, because I don't.

Comment: @DaveNewton i have added code to this answer to understand better

Comment: @hussain Ew don't-if you have additional context please edit the question. Based on the code in your question this answer is correct-it runs fine.